# DJANGO models proxy inharitence

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to add the methods of the 'tools' class for 2 of my django model calss.
Each class will use the same methods with it's own model eample:

```
class mapA(models.Model):
     mInd = models.IntegerField()
     scId = models.IntegerField()

class mapB(models.Model):
     mInd = models.IntegerField()
     scId2 = models.IntegerField()
```

I would like to add the methods like checkInput() to both of them. 
So I could run:

```
mapBInstance.checkInput();
mapAInstance.checkInput();
```

Ech time the checkInput runs over the data in the mapA or mapB.

I thought about creating a tools class & let each model to inherit from it. 
This way the tools class will have logic which is identical to both maps.

When I read the django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) I didn't see example to this case only close solutions. 
Is this the correct solution (to use the proxy class)?

```
class Tools():
   def __init__():
      ...init class...
   def checkInput():
       ..make the checks..

class MapA(Tools, models.Model):
     mInd = models.IntegerField()
     scId = models.IntegerField()

     def checkSelf():
         self.checkInput(self.objects.filter(....))

class MapB(Tools, models.Model):
     mIndB = models.IntegerField()
     scIdB = models.IntegerField()
     def checkSelf():
         self.checkInput(self.objects.filter(....))
```

Comment: No, `tools` is just a mixin class, it doesn't define any model (table) which is when you'd need a proxy model. ps: `this` is spelled `self` in Python.

Comment: TY, I've updated is this a correct solution?

Comment: See @frnhr's answer. You don't need to override checkInput, but since `.objects.filter(...)` is a class-method (ie. it cannot be called on `self`), perhaps `checkInput` ought to be a class method too? (not enough info to tell though).

Comment: finally got you both! thank you both :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things...

---

There is no `this` in Python, it's called `self`.

---

If you're in Python 2.x, `tools` should inherit from `object`. In Python 3, it's implicit, but doesn't hurt:

```
class tools(object):
    ...
```

---

If you're overriding `__init__` in your mixin class (`tools`), then `map` classes should probably inherit from it *first*:

```
class mapA(tools, models.Model):
    ...
```

Only override `__init__` if you really need to, it can get complicated.

---

Class names are pretty much always in CamelCase. This is not required, but is a convention. Also, It's a good idea to name mixin classes transparently:

```
class ToolsMixin(object):
    ...

class MapA(ToolsMixin, models.Model):
    ...
```

---

Other then all that, you perfectly can add a method in a mixin and use it in your models. No need for Django proxy models.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `MapA` and `MapB` (it would be really helpful if you followed [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) to be distinct models, proxy models won't help you. A proxy model is a model that is different in Python, but in the database it is exactly the same as the model it inherits from. Creating a proxy model that doesn't directly inherit from a single concrete model (one that has a table in the database) is an error.

What you're looking for is an abstract base class:

```
class Tools(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class MapA(Tools):
    ...

class MapB(Tools):
    ...
```

An abstract model does *not* create its own table in the database. Instead, it is as if everything defined in `Tools` has been defined in both `MapA` and `MapB`, but the `Tools` class is otherwise ignored. This allows you to specify all the methods and fields just once, but still have two separate tables in the database.

Comment: Im trying to avoid duplicating the data (it isn't 100% compatible) + the tools class is only in order to be as oop as I can (lazy :P ) and use the same code once..